# Shrinking 150 TB data warehouse instance is feasible option?

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure, azure-sql-data-warehouse

We are using azure SQL data warehouse(azure synapse analytics) with size of 150 TB among which 75 TB is used and we are planning to shrink database with help of MS. What are the challenges should we aware of before doing it ?

- Estimated downtime: 12 to 24 Hrs
- Clustered column store index is enabled on instance

Comment: MS should be able to help you with that. _Clustered column store index_ is always enabled on azure synapse analytics.

Comment: Thanks @Nick.McDermaid for response. Yes definitely MS is helping us.And we can disable CCI on azure synapse analytics just for your reference

Comment: You can choose for each table to not have a CCI. I’ve ever heard of disabling it.

Comment: Yes there is option to disable but its only done by MS